# Extending awk one-liner from identifying matching pair of columns (row by row), to multiple columns

Tags: awk, cygwin

I am using Win7 with Cygwin. I have a one-liner that will work for identifying matches in a PAIR of columns, but when I try to introduce additional columns (i.e. >2) I cannot get it to work. So the following works for me:

```
gawk -F "^" '{ if ($3 == $7) print "0"; else print $3,$7; }' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

However when I add in another pair of columns I get syntax errors:

```
gawk -F "^" '{ if ($3 == $7 || $3 == $11) print "0"; else print $3,$7,$11; }' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

So something is wrong with the command, but the error messages are not really helpful to me. When I substitute "&&" for "||" I also get errors ("unexpected newline or end of string" straight after the first "$7" and also "$3 is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file").

So here's an example input file, containing the three rows, with "^" as column delimiter:

```
paris^london^new york^paris^rome^paris

paris^london^munich^paris^rome^paris

paris^london^munich^berlin^rome^paris
```

I want to be able to see if, in each row of the file, columns 1, 4, and 6 match each other. So in this case, row 1 is "yes", row 2 is "yes" and row 3 is "no". So the output should show either "0" for "yes" or repeat the whole row for "no". So output would be:

```
0
0
paris^london^munich^berlin^rome^paris
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: (1) check your command-line because your script work as expected. (2) in your example condition should be `$1 == $4 && $1 == $6`

Comment: As @Costas mentioned, the syntac is ok. There might be some Windows specific quirks. What you can do is try putting your awk script into a file and invoke `gawk -F "^" -f scr_file input_file > output_file` . See if that works

Comment: No, as I said, the "$1 == $4 && $1 == $6" format doesn't work either. And I don't understand what "check your command-line because your script work as expected" means exactly.

Comment: This mean that your expression is syntaxically correct and do work in linux shell (have tested). The problem is in your cygwin implemetation.

Comment: Are you typing this in bash or in cmd? If you're using cmd, you can't use sh quoting.

Comment: @Gilles it's going in a batch file and/or being typed into the Command Prompt

Comment: Then you can't use sh/bash syntax! You need to quote your awk command for cmd instead. That's off-topic here since it's a Windows question, I flagged for migration to [su] (do not repost).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Windows's cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid `||` and `&&`

- For `&&` test

  `gawk -F "^" '$3 == $7{if($3 == $11){print "0"; next;}}{print $3,$7,$11}'`
- For `||` test

  `gawk -F "^" '$3 == $7{print "0"; next;}$3 == $11{print "0"; next;}{print $3,$7,$11}'`

Comment: Thanks Costas ... definitely the right track now, it's generating outputs ... but not quite doing what it should. The second one-liner you wrote will give a "0" if $3 = $7, irrespective of what else is happening on that line. But it needs to give a "0" only if $3 = $7 AND if $3 = $11 AND whatever other equivalences are written in there. So your one-liner effectively gives up on the line if the first equivalence ($3=$7) is met, kind of like an Excel IF statement, but I need it to operate more like an Excel IF(AND) statement.

Comment: @Simonmdr; You should rather fix the problem rather than working on the symptoms.

Comment: @Costas; Why avoid a standard `awk` construct with operators`||` and `&&`? - I certainly used those also in a Cygwin `bash` in the past.

Comment: @Janis: my motivation is quite simple. Identifying the specifics of my "Cygwin installation problem" (and I have just reinstalled Cygwin, and the one-liner still doesn't work) is kind of fruitless for me, given my low level of knowledge. Identifying a workaround is not fruitless (for me, anyway). And this is probably the first time I've had a syntax error with Cygwin that I couldn't solve, suggesting, indeed, some sort of installation problem, but one that might not justify throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: @Simonmdr; To narrow down the problem it would be helpful to know whether Amit Kumar's advice solves the issue.

Comment: @Simonmdr The first-onliner will do what you wants

Comment: @Janis - so Amit's advice, which I followed blindly because I wasn't quite sure what was happening, gave me a different set of error messages. Basically, when I put this into a file:  gawk -F "^" '{ if ($3 == $7 || $3 == $11) print "0"; else print $3,$7,$11; }' infile.txt > outfile.txt  and invoke it as suggested, I get a couple of error messages, with the first one referring to the first single quote mark at character position 13: "invalid character ''' in expression" 
Then below that it tells me for the very same character (i.e. the first single quote mark): "syntax error".

Comment: @Costas your first option works ... thanks very much. Stuffed if I know what is going on here. One thing - can you just extend the command to a third equivalence pair (e.g. $3 == $7 AND say $3 == $11 AND say $3 == $15) because with the two there now I'm not QUITE able to lock in on the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally. I'm using Cygwin with Win7. The single quote marks were no good, so replacing ALL single quotes with double quotes fixed up the syntax, and additionally, "||" was no good, but "&&" works fine. So the following works:

gawk -F "^" "{ if ($1 == $2 && $3 == $4 && $4 == $5 && $5 == $6) print 0; else print $1,$2,$3; }" infile.txt > outfile.txt